# GeoServer and NetCDF - Gap around prime meridian

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

I'm attempting to use GeoServer to publish NetCDF layers. So far has been working well using EPSG:4326 (the native srs) as reference system in the GetMap request. In this case the image from GeoServer looks something like below

[image]

(request parameters "bbox=-90%2C-77.5%2C90%2C79.5&width=768&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=image/png")

If the reference system in the request is changed to EPSG:3857 (Mercator) however, a small gap appears around the prime meridian as seen in below image

[image]

(request parameters bbox=-10018754.17%2C-14106322.01%2C10018754.17%2C15225854.97&width=768&height=768&crs=EPSG%3A3857&format=image/png)

The NetCDF file has 1°x1° spatial resolution and longitude axis 0°-359°.

I have tried changing the request bbox parameters, the bounding boxes for the layer in GeoServer as well as changing the style to the default raster style, but the gap still shows.

How do I get rid of this gap?